# Pass a SQL condition as a OleDb parameter

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sqlparameter, prepared-statement, oledbparameter

I have following code:

```
Dim executedCmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = m_dbMgr.GetCommand()
executedCmd.CommandText = "select * from [Parameters] where "
Dim SQLcondition As String = String.Empty
For i As Integer = 0 To ParameterName.Count - 1
 executedCmd.CommandText += "ParameterName = @parametername" + i.ToString() + " and ParameterValue @ParamaterCondition" + i.ToString() + " @ParameterValue" + i.ToString()
 executedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametername" + i.ToString(), ParameterName(i))
 executedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterValue" + i.ToString(), ParameterValue(i))
 executedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamaterCondition" + i.ToString(), Condition(i))
Next
```

`ParameterName`, `ParameterValue`, `ParameterCondition` all are same length `ArrayList`, but the code does not work properly. I have verified all the variables have values.

When I run the code it reports a syntax error: "missing operations in query expression"

The problem is that `ParameterCondition` has values like (`'>'`, `'<'`, `'='`,.... some logical SQL operators).

Edit: How can I include conditions in parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Add `1 = 1` after where to simplify building logical expression. Notice that all conditions added by `AND` logical operator. You can generate parameter name from columns name.

```
executedCmd.CommandText = "select * from [Parameters] where 1 = 1"

....
executedCmd.CommandText += " AND " + ParameterName(i) + " " + Condition(i) + " @" + ParameterName(i)
executedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + ParameterName(i), ParameterValue(i))
```

ParameterCondition must all be binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

The database engine would check the syntax of the SQL statement before it replaces the parameters with values. So somethinhg like "WHERE @p1 @p2 @p3" will not be parsed correctly.
Replace your condition with a string-expression e.g.

```
commandtext = parameterName + condition + " @p1"
```

Comment: How to parameterised that condition? is there is a way?